# how do i update textview in fragments ___android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview, broadcastreceiver

**i am working on a app which show battery temperature and other info of battery.
for that i have implemented swipe tabs with fragments.
but when i try to update the textview in my fragment with battery temperature the app force closes. the code doesnt show any error.it is runtime error.
fragment xml file has just relativelayout and textview.
swipetabs are working nice if i not try to update temprature.
battery temp. is showing well when run in layout without tabs. 
only 2 tabs are there and for battery information i have used braodcast_receiver.
please give some solution for this**

code for temprature fragment

```
package com.example.batterytemppro;


import android.app.Activity;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class temprature_fragment extends Fragment{

TextView tvtemp;
BatteryManager batteryman;
 Context context;;
 double i,j;
 //Intent intent;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.temprature_xml, container, false);
    tvtemp=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.textViewtemp);
    //tvtemp.setText("this is not working");

    batteryknow bk=new batteryknow();
    context.getApplicationContext();
    context.registerReceiver(bk, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));


    return rootview;



    }


public class batteryknow extends BroadcastReceiver {


    BatteryManager bm;
    TextView tvtemp;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         i =intent.getIntExtra(bm.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
         j=i/10;
        tvtemp.setText(""+j);

    }

}   

}
```

**code for mainactivity.class**

```
package com.example.batterytemppro;   


//import com.example.batterytemppro.temprature_fragment.batteryknow;

import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements TabListener, 
OnPageChangeListener {

ViewPager viewpager;
ActionBar actionbar;
String [] tabs={"Temperature","Information"};
temprature_fragment tempt;
double i,j;
TextView tvtemp;
Intent intent;
BatteryManager bm;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    viewpager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionbar=getActionBar();
    actionbar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(actionbar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);


    viewpager.setAdapter(new TabpageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);



    for(String tab_host:tabs)
    {
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(tab_host).setTabListener(this));

    }   

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

  }

}
```

**code for pageadpter class**

```
package com.example.batterytemppro;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class TabpageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    public TabpageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

   switch (position) {

   case 0:

       return new temprature_fragment();

   case 1:

       return new information_fragment();


}           

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 2;
}   

}
```

Comment: You shoul read this article:  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to change the textview from a `BroadcastReceiver` which runs a different thread than the UI thread. Android doesn't allow you to make changes to the UI from outside the UI thread. change you `BroadcastReceiver` to this:

```
public class batteryknow extends BroadcastReceiver {


    BatteryManager bm;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         i =intent.getIntExtra(bm.EXTRA_TEMPERATURE, 0);
         j=i/10;

         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
         {
             public void run() 
             {
                 tvtemp.setText(""+j);
             }
         });                
     }
}
```

One last thing you need to change is the tvtemp (`TextView`) is null. You have to declare it as a final in the fragment class

Comment: thanks for your answer.

but i solved the problem.
the braodcastreceiver does not getting the proper context so i just provided getactivity() as context parameter.